# ошибка TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable при запуске

Tags: python

```
elif smsg[0].lower() in ["проверить"] and str(user_id) in conversations[str(peer_id-CHAT_ID_MIN)]['admins']:
    convers=[2000000013,2000000014,2000000015,2000000017,2000000020,2000000024,2000000016,2000000027,2000000019,2000000012,2000000032,2000000030,2000000031,2000000033,2000000035,2000000036,2000000037]
    code='''var post = [];
    var peer_ids={};
    var i=0;
    while (i<{}) {{
    post.push(API.messages.getConversationMembers({{"peer_id": peer_ids[i]}}));
    i=i+1;
    }}
    return post;'''.format(str(convers),len(convers))
    mem=self.vk_api.execute(code=code) 
    mem=[[item["member_id"] for item in i["items"] if item['member_id']>0] for i in mem]
    mem={convers[i]: mem[i] for i in range(len(convers))}                                
    v=int(self.uid(smsg[1]))
    convers=[int(abcde) for abcde in convers if v in mem[abcde]]
    if convers==[]: answer="Этого пользователя нет в беседах"
    else: 
        answer=' '
        for j in convers:
            if j == 2000000013:
                answer+='OMINI_1;\n '
            elif j == 2000000014:
                answer+='OMINI_2;\n '
            elif j == 2000000015:
                answer+='OMINI_3;\n '
            elif j == 2000000017:
                answer+='OMINI_4;\n '
            elif j == 2000000020:
                answer+='OMINI_5;\n '
            elif j == 2000000024:
                answer+='OMINI_6;\n '
            elif j == 2000000016:
                answer+='OMINI_HENT_1;\n '
            elif j == 2000000027:
                answer+='OMINI_HENT_2;\n '
            elif j == 2000000012:
                answer+='ADMIN_1;\n '
            elif j == 2000000019:
                answer+='CASINO;\n '
            elif j == 2000000031:
                answer+='ADMIN_2;\n '
            elif j == 2000000032:
                answer+='DRIMI_HENT_1;\n '
            elif j == 2000000030:
                answer+='DRIMI_1;\n '
            elif j == 2000000033:
                answer+='DRIMI_2;\n '
            elif j == 2000000035:
                answer+='CLAN_FULLHACK;\n '
            elif j == 2000000036:
                answer+='CLAN_SCARLETAGONY;\n '
            elif j == 2000000037:
                answer+='CLAN_DNDWM;\n '
    self.sendmsg(peer_id=peer_id,message='[id{}|{}]: '.format(str(v), self.username(v))+'\n' +answer)
```

Ошибка:

```
File "Zerochka.py", line 3822, in <listcomp> mem=[[item["member_id"] for item in i["items"] if item['member_id']>0] for i in mem] TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Код крайне желательно предоставлять целиком. Не может код Python начинаться с `elif`

Comment: дело в том, что это отдельный кусок кода, это вк бот и целый код очень длинный

Comment: честно сказать он ещё вчера нормально работал и я его не трогал, а сегодня вылезла вот такая ошибка

Comment: Давай трассу стека в вопрос, иначе в этом месиве не захочется разбираться :)

Answer (score 2):

> TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Это ошибка означает, что у вас есть объект типа `bool` (`True` или `False`) и у него были вызваны квадратные скобки (`subscriptable` это оно).

Ошибка произошла в этой строке:

```
mem=[[item["member_id"] for item in i["items"] if item['member_id']>0] for i in mem]
```

Соответственно, или в `i["items"]` переменная `i` является `bool`, или в `item["member_id"]` переменная `item` является `bool`.

Советую данные начать логировать (хотя бы в `print`) и смотреть по логам где начались аномалии

---

**PS.**

Насчет ошибки, и как ее повторить:

```
>>> i = True
>>> i[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```